# CarrierWave save NULL at file column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

im using model called Photo that references Uploader class..

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :album_id
  belongs_to :album
  mount_uploader :photo_image, PhotosUploader
end



class Album < ActiveRecord::Base    
  attr_accessible :title, :autor, :photos_attributes
  has_many :photos, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos  
end
```

but.. when i try to save new Album (or edit, whatever..) with image it not save a file (the collumn photo_image is saved as NULL and file not stored too.

... views/albums/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :photos do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :photo_image %><br />
        <%= f.file_field :photo_image %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

any suggestion?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails 3.1.3 with ruby 1.9.3-rc1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try to add `:photo_image` to `attr_accessible` at Photo model, it's maybe could help you.

Also check your `log/development.log`

Comment: duh.. works fine! i did think that was needed add photo_image as acessible only at Album model. tks!

Comment: without it Rails will just ignore data that comes after submit. good luck!:)