# CarrierWave. Impossible to save the file with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have model `Document`:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

And two classes inherited from `Document`:

`License`:

```
class License < Document
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader
end
```

And `Certificate`

```
class Certificate < Document
  mount_uploader :file, DocumentUploader
end
```

And when I try to do `current_company.licenses.create(...)` or same action for the certificate, always all params are saved, besides `file`, which always is `nil`

Also I've tried to mount `file` inside of `Document` model... Help me please.

Here is logs:

```
Started POST "/companies/1/verified" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Mar 19 09:33:41 +0200 2012
Processing by CompaniesController#verified as HTML
  Parameters: {"verified"=>{"certificate"=>{"name"=>"Certificate", "file"=>"test.png"}, "insured"=>"2000000", "suppliers"=>"", "license"=>{"name"=>"License", "file"=>"test.png"}}, "authenticity_token"=>"0hIn41Tjonm/AXZBKM1PE/tjQxJDLqZaojMTHDoZq2k=", "id"=>"1", "utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Update verifications"}
  Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "documents" ("company_id", "created_at", "file", "name", "type", "updated_at", "verified") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["company_id", 1], ["created_at", Mon, 19 Mar 2012 07:33:41 UTC +00:00], ["file", nil], ["name", "License"], ["type", "License"], ["updated_at", Mon, 19 Mar 2012 07:33:41 UTC +00:00], ["verified", false]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "documents" ("company_id", "created_at", "file", "name", "type", "updated_at", "verified") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["company_id", 1], ["created_at", Mon, 19 Mar 2012 07:33:41 UTC +00:00], ["file", nil], ["name", "Certificate"], ["type", "Certificate"], ["updated_at", Mon, 19 Mar 2012 07:33:41 UTC +00:00], ["verified", false]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/company/profile
Completed 302 Found in 18ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplication of [CarrierWave save NULL at file column][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134339/carrierwave-save-null-at-file-column

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've set the form that you've uploading the file with to have a multipart payload?

If not the file won't get sent on submission, and rails will only receive the textual form data. Inside the form_helper tag you'll need to add.

```
:html => {:multipart => true}
```